# Spark: Load/Parse space separated plus quoted strings

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have records like below.

Space delimited/separated:

```
2015-07-22 5555 9999 "abc bbc 777" "FFF/5.0 (NTFS NT 6.1)"
2015-07-16 1111 7777 "7873 b34 bt57" "77/99 (TT; 420; ty:39.0) aa/11.0"
```

I would like to know if there is any direct way to splitting/separating fields 4 and 5 incase if they are double quoted
using sc.textfile and spark.read.format()?

Expected output:

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Date       |Value1    |Value2     |Value3                     |Value3                           |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2015-07-22 |5555      |9999       |abc bbc 777                |FFF/5.0 (NTFS NT 6.1)
    2015-07-16 |1111      |7777       |7873 b34 bt57              |77/99 (TT; 420; ty:39.0) aa/11.0 |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If there is already a solution similar to this please point to that. Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard csv reader will be able to read this format just fine

```
scala> spark.read.option("delimiter", " ").csv(pathToFile).show
+----------+----+----+-------------+--------------------+
|       _c0| _c1| _c2|          _c3|                 _c4|
+----------+----+----+-------------+--------------------+
|2015-07-22|5555|9999|  abc bbc 777|FFF/5.0 (NTFS NT ...|
|2015-07-16|1111|7777|7873 b34 bt57|77/99 (TT; 420; t...|
+----------+----+----+-------------+--------------------+
```